# Can selenium Grid and Node URLs be used with security?

Tags: http, selenium, selenium-webdriver, https

I am in a situation where I am running my GridServer and Nodes on the cloud and

when I want to access the Grid I use:
`http://someip:4444/grid/console`

When I want to access the node I use:
`http:someip:<nodeport>/wd/hub`

I think its a kind of threat as the IPs are publicly accessible. How can I limit that it shouldn't be opened by external users.

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium is not supporting that.

For that purposes you should make a p2p connection between you and grid.
VPN or ssh tunnel will work. Just forward remote server port to a local port:

```
ssh user@SERVER -L 4444:127.0.0.1:4444
```

Now, connecting to a local 4444 port will forward you to the remote address "SERVER". All the connection is secured by ssh login/password now and the traffic is hidden in a secure tunnel.

Comment: But, how would you handle grid-hub relationship with VPN or ssh tunnel?

Comment: Really simple. You will just change the IP addresses of the grid master/slaves. For example if you will use VPN, you can setup the vpn server on a grid maser server and connect to that VPN server from all the hubs.