# Grid : How to make hub password protected

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I am planning to deploy my hub in internet.I want only particular nodes to connect to my hub(Restricting unknown nodes from connecting to my hub).Currently i am doing it in firewall level.Is there any feature in grid level to make hub password protected ie)when nodes connect to a hub they are required to enter a password to connect to hub or any other mechanism through which we can block unknown nodes from connecting to hub

I went through the selenium grid [docs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) couldn't find one

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Selenium Grid don't has such option and you may need to write your own method for that.

Using firewall is the better approach.

Refer: [Can selenium Grid and Node URLs be used with security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427771/can-selenium-grid-and-node-urls-be-used-with-security) and [Security in Selenium 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951371/security-in-selenium-2)

[Gridlastic](https://gridlastic.com/selenium-grid-demo.html) is a good tool that can help you setup firewall with Selenium Grid.

[Selenium Grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2#Using_grid_to_run_tests) can be helpful when you want to authenticate the node before running test on them, eg. authentication on [Saucelabs](https://docs.saucelabs.com/tutorials/java/#the-test-class) by URL.

Also Refer: [Can Selenium Grid be configured to require authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593670/can-selenium-grid-be-configured-to-require-authentication)

Comment: Thanks for the reply....started writing my own code for making hub password protected

Comment: Do you remember how you accomplished this?